# android Contacts deletion

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have a method that deletes a particular number from from a contact and not the whole contact. (For eg. if a name has 2 contacts, i let user delete only one number, and not the whole number).
Hence, for contacts containing a single number, after deletion for the single number, the contact remains with only a name and no associated number.
To delete such im  using a method given below, The method works fine, and the empty contacts are removed, but it doesn't work always.
It misbehaves sometimes and the empty contact remains.
And sometimes it works.
It always works for a name containing more than one number(when the numbers are deleted, empty contact also deleted using the method below).
For names(contacts) containing a single number, it works properly and deletes the empty contact (after number being deleted), but only sometimes.

Here is how im deleting "just a number" from a contact.

```
 public void updateContact(String contactId, String type) {
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();


   /* String selectPhone = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" +
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'" + " AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + "=?";
    String[] phoneArgs = new String[]{contactId, type};

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI).withSelection(selectPhone, phoneArgs).build());

*/
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(ContactsContract.RawContacts.Data._ID + "=? and " + ContactsContract.RawContacts.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE})
            .build());



    try {
        getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is the method i'm using to delete an empty contact, i call this after deleting number using above contacts in an asynTask.

```
   public void emptyRemover(String s, String name) {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME)).equalsIgnoreCase(name)
                /*||cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID)).equalsIgnoreCase(s)*/){
            if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))==0) {
                String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
                contentResolver.delete(uri, null, null);
            }
        }
    }
    cursor.close();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

When deleting a raw contact at `ContactsContract.RawContacts` you have to take in account that:

> The invocation of resolver.delete(...), does not immediately delete a
>   raw contacts row. Instead, it sets the DELETED flag on the raw contact
>   and removes the raw contact from its aggregate contact. The sync
>   adapter then deletes the raw contact from the server and finalizes
>   phone-side deletion by calling resolver.delete(...) again and passing
>   the CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER query parameter.
>   Some sync adapters are read-only, meaning that they only sync
>   server-side changes to the phone, but not the reverse. If one of those
>   raw contacts is marked for deletion, it will remain on the phone.
>   However it will be effectively invisible, because it will not be part
>   of any aggregate contact.

This is why sometimes you see it effectively deleted and sometimes don't. So, you have to call two times the delete operation, like this:

```
Uri rawUri = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true").build();    

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI).
    withSelection(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID + "=? AND "
                  +ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE+ "=? AND "
                  +ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME+ "=?"
                  ,params).build()); //sets deleted flag to 1

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(rawUri).
    withSelection(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID + "=? AND "
                 +ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE+ "=? AND "
                 +ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME+ "=?"
                 ,params).build()); //erases
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: When deleting the last `ContactsContract.RawContacts` linked with a `ContactsContract.Contacts` the contact itself is automatically deleted because "When data in or associated with the RawContacts table is changed, the affected aggregate contacts are updated as necessary" as quoted from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html

Comment: But do you really have to do this twice if you are allready a syncadapter?

Comment: You sir, safed my ass. Thanks a lot!